# Can somebody please explain this behaviour?

Tags: swift

Let's say I have a class:

```
class MyClass {
    var fnc: () -> Void
    var int = 1

    init(_ fnc: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.fnc = fnc
    }
}
```

And I do the following:

```
var foo: MyClass?
foo = MyClass { [weak foo] in
    print("Foo: \(foo?.int)")
}
foo?.fnc()
```

I was expecting to get: `Foo: Optional(1)`
Instead I get: `Foo: nil`

If you don't "weakify" foo:

```
var foo: MyClass?
foo = MyClass {
    print("Foo: \(foo?.int)")
}
foo?.fnc()
```

Indeed I get the expected: `Foo: Optional(1)`

Why doesn't the first option capture `foo`?

I am certain `foo` is not deallocated by the time `foo?.fnc()` is called. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square brackets `[...]` in the closure are called *Capture List*

In the first example you are **capturing** `foo`.

Regardless what's happening later the uninitialized `foo` is passed in the closure.